# How do I modify the quantity of an item in a list?

Tags: python, function, loops, class, parameters

I have to write a code that modifies the quantity of an item in a shopping cart. Initially, I have a class names ItemToPurhcase that takes in the item's name, quantity, price and description. Under ShoppingCart class, function modify_item()
modifies an item's quantity. Has a parameter of type ItemToPurchase. Does not return anything.
If item can be found (by name) in cart, modify item in cart.
If item cannot be found (by name) in cart, output this message: **Item not found in cart. Nothing modified.**
My code so far:

```
class ItemToPurchase:
    def __init__(self, name="none", price=0, quantity=0, descrip='none'):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price
        self.descrip = descrip

    def print_item_cost():
        print(self.name + ' ' + str(self.quantity) + '@ $' + str(self.price) + '= $' + str(self.price * self.quantity))

    def print_item_description(ItemToPurchase):
        print(self.name + ':' + str(self.descrip)

class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, customer_name='none', current_date='January 1, 2016', cart_items):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.currend_date = current_date
        self.cart_items = []

    def add_item(self, ItemToPurchase):
        self.cart_items.append(ItemToPurchase)
        
    def remove_item(self, item_name):
        while item_name in self.cart_items:
            del self.cart_items[item_name]
        if item_name not in self.cart_items:
            print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed')

    def modify_item(self, ItemToPurchase):
        if name in self.cart_items:
```

I need help completing the function.

Comment: You're deleting the item from the cart before you check to see if it's there.

Comment: Is `cart_items` a list of names, or a list of `ItemToPurchase` instances?

Comment: There's no `name` parameter to `modify_item()`.

Comment: @Barmar car_items is a list of ItemToPurchase

Comment: `name` is not a list index, `self.cart_items[name]` makes no sense.

Comment: @Samwise Basically, the user types in an option from a menu. If the option is a specific letter, then the program runs the function.

Comment: If it's not a list of names, why are you using `name in self.cart_items`?

Comment: What does that have to do with anything Samwise said? The problem is you have `if name not in self.cart_items:` *after* you've run the loop that removes it. So it will always say that the item was not found. You should check for the item first.

Comment: You have two `class ItemToPurchase`. Why? A class can't be its own superclass.

Comment: `self.description` should be `self.descip`. And `set_description()` should set it to the parameter, not `none`.

Comment: To be honest with you, the instructions for this code were a little confusing. We were instructed to create a list. add_item() basically adds an item to cart_items list. I believe that the reason why we were instructed to set the parameter to ItemToPurchase is because the list also should contain the characteristics of the item.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I need help completing the function."  This is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) that can be answered in this format. Please read [ask], and then *think* about the next steps of the process. They were laid out for you in the assignment: "If item can be found (by name) in cart" - do you know how to check? (Hint: what do you imagine is the intended purpose of the `ItemToPurchase` parameter?) "modify item in cart." Okay, so - can you *refer to* the item? Now that you have the item, can you change its quantity?

Comment: (Hint: in the `remove_name` method, what is the purpose of `del self.cart_items[item_name]`? Do you see how to modify that in order to access an item, rather than deleting it?) (Hint: in the `__init__` for the `ItemToPurchase` class, how do you set the initial quantity for the new item? Can you see how to use the same logic to *change* the quantity of an item? Now that you have access to it?)

Answer (score 0):

The shopping cart doesn't contain names, it contains `ItemToPurchase`. So you can't just check if the name is in the list, you have to check whether any of the items in the list has a `.name` attribute that matches.

The `modify_item` function needs to take the new quantity as a parameter. Then it can loop through the cart items and update the quantity.

```
def remove_item(self, item_name):
    old_len = len(self.cart_items)
    self.cart_items = [item for item in self.cart_items if item.name != item_name]
    if len(self.cart_items) == old_len:
        print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed')

def modify_item(self, item_name, new_quantity):
    for item in enumerate(cart_items):
        if item.name == item_name:
            item.quantity = new_quantity
            break
    else:
        print("Item not found in cart. Nothing modified")
```

Comment: Does the function modify_item() change the quantity of the item?

Comment: If `new_item` has a different quantity, it does.

Comment: What is it supposed to change the quantity to?

Comment: The user is going to input the quantity and it should change the quantity to that input.

Comment: But the new quantity isn't a parameter to the function, so how is it supposed to know what to change it to?

Comment: I've added `new_quantity` as a parameter and updated the answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I was confused too. We have been instructed to set the parameter to the type ItemToPurchase. Maybe something like item.quantity? I am not sure.

Comment: We can't help you read the assignment. If something is unclear about *what the code is supposed to do*, please *talk to your instructor*.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your code look like this:

```
def modify_item(self, item: ItemToPurchase):
    item_names = [item.name for item in self.cart_items]
    if item.name in item_names:
        spot = item_names.index(item.name)
        self.cart_items[spot] = item
    else:
        return "Item not found in cart. Nothing modified."
```

The item parameter takes an instance of the ItemToPurchase Class, and then the function uses list comprehension to find the names of all of the items in the cart. Then it checks if the name of the item to be modified is already in the cart before it finds what spot in the list that item is at and then changes the item. Otherwise, it returns  "Item not found in cart. Nothing modified."

Answer (score 0):

I also edited the rest of your code to get rid of the rest of the bugs:

```
class ItemToPurchase:
    def __init__(self, name="none", price=0, quantity=0):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = 0
        self.description = 'none'

    def set_description(self, descrip):
        self.description = descrip

    def print_item_description(self):
        print(self.name + ':' + str(self.description))

    def print_item_cost(self):
        print(self.name + ' ' + str(self.quantity) + '@ $' + str(self.price) + '= $' + str(self.price * self.quantity))


class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, cart_items: list, customer_name='none', current_date='January 1, 2016'):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.current_date = current_date
        self.cart_items = cart_items

    def add_item(self, new_item):
        self.cart_items.append(new_item)

    def remove_item(self, item_name):
        item_names = [item.name for item in self.cart_items]
        if item_name in item_names:
            spot = item_names.index(item_name)
            del self.cart_items[spot]
        if item_name not in self.cart_items:
            print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed')

    def modify_item(self, item: ItemToPurchase):
        item_names = [item.name for item in self.cart_items]
        if item.name in item_names:
            spot = item_names.index(item.name)
            self.cart_items[spot] = item
        else:
            return "Item not found in cart. Nothing modified."
```